# How to generate a FULL thread dump from Weblogic using the Weblogic Console or WLST?

Tags: java, weblogic, thread-dump

I am looking for a way to generate a FULL thread dump from the `Weblogic` console and/or `WLST`.  I do not have access to the server where `Weblogic` is running so I cannot send a QUIT signal or use the `jstack` utility.  I am aware that you can dump the thread stacks in the `Weblogic` console, or use `WLST` to do the same via the `threadDump()` method, but this does not appear to be a **complete** thread dump (does not contain info on every thread in the JVM, does not display thread locking information) and it does not appear to be parseable by the various thread dump analysis utilities (tda, samurai, etc.).  Is there a way to accomplish what I am looking to do?